# Generate html table from json data with different table header other than json key

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have json file

```json
    [
        {
            "id": "1234",
            "desc": "desc",
            "author": "abcd"
        },
        {
            "id": "1234",
            "desc": "desc",
            "author": "abcd"
        },
        {
            "id": "1234",
            "desc": "desc",
            "author": "abcd"

        }
    ]
}
```

need to generate dynamic html table from `JSON` using JavaScript and column headers should not be the `JSON` key .and value of column header should be

```
Book ID |Book name|Author name | SUBMIT

|:----  |:------:|       -----:|--------:|

| One   | Two    |       Three |Four:|
```

In 4th column , it should be a button with `onclick` function.

I tried to generate table. But unable to map the `JSON` value to column header name other than `JSON` key. and how to add extra column with a button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        th, td, p, input, h3 {
            font:15px 'Segoe UI';
        }
        table, th, td {
            border: solid 1px #ddd;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 2px 3px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        th {
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type='button' onclick='tableFromJson()'
       value='Submitted Books' />

<p id='showData'></p>

<p id='msg'></p>
</body>


</html>
```

Above code will generate table with 3 headers and header name as json key. Inside col[] ,If I give correct columns headers , then it is not mapping properly

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java, please provide only relevant tags when asking questions

Comment: _"I tried to generate table"_ - please may you add this effort to the question as a [mcve]?

Comment: Above code will generate table with 3 headers and header name as json key. Inside col[] ,If I give correct columns headers , then it is not mapping properly

Comment: What is the content text of the fourth column?

Comment: 4th column , it should be a button with onclick function.

Answer (score 1):

I refactored you code a bit. I replaced the for loop with `forEach()` that I find more readable.

The event listener for the buttons in the table is on the `<div>` that holds the table. The reason is that you dont need to assign new event listeners if the table is rendered again. The only thing you need to do is to test if it was a button that was clicked.

```js
var submitBooks = document.getElementById('submitBooks');
var showData = document.getElementById('showData');

submitBooks.addEventListener('click', tableFromJson);

showData.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON'){
    console.log(e.target.attributes.item('data-id').value);
  }
});

function tableFromJson() {
  // the json data. (you can change the values for output.)
  var details = [{
      "id": "11256310",
      "desc": "desc",
      "author": "abc",

    },
    {
      "id": "33856310",
      "desc": "desca",
      "author": "abcA",

    },
    {
      "id": "73856310",
      "desc": "descB",
      "author": "cBonfigadminB",

    }
  ];

  // Extract value from table header.

  var cols = ['id', 'desc', 'author', 'submit'];


  // Create a table.
  var table = document.createElement("table");

  // Create table header row
  var tr = table.insertRow(); // table row.

  cols.forEach(col => {
    let th = document.createElement("th"); // table header.
    th.innerHTML = col;
    tr.appendChild(th);
  });

  // add json data to the table as rows.
  details.forEach(detail => {
    let tr = table.insertRow();
    Object.keys(detail).forEach(key => {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell();
      tabCell.innerHTML = detail[key];
    });
    let tabCell = tr.insertCell();
    let button = document.createElement('BUTTON'); // create button
    button.textContent = 'Submit';
    let dataid = document.createAttribute('data-id'); // attribute for button what holds id
    dataid.value = detail.id;
    button.attributes.setNamedItem(dataid);
    tabCell.append(button);
  });


  // Now, add the newly created table with json data, to a container.
  var divShowData = document.getElementById('showData');
  divShowData.innerHTML = "";
  divShowData.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
th,
td,
p,
input,
h3 {
  font: 15px 'Segoe UI';
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input id="submitBooks" type='button' value='Submitted Books' />
<p id='showData'></p>
<p id='msg'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it almost correct, but I think the order is just wrong.

```
for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) { // only for table cells, not header
  var th = document.createElement("th"); // should be outside loop
  th.innerHTML = col[i]; // table cells
  tr.appendChild(th); // this will append 3 headers, each time on the loop
}
```

You should instead use something like:

```
var th = document.createElement("th")

for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
  var tabCell = th.insertCell(-1)
  tabCell.innerHTML = col[i]
}

tr.appendChild(th)
```

It's just a rough idea to show you, I've not tested it myself, just used what you did and changed it up a bit.